# Where has Lipo tool gone in XCode 4/5?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, lipo

I had lipo on my command-line - I think as a left-over from XCode 3.2. I removed that old version today and now my scripts using `LIPO=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo` don't work!

Where can I find the location of Lipo now I'm using XCode 4/5? Will it be installed by default, or do I have to get an extra toolset from Apple? I noticed that XCode builds are still creating unified libs OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple moved the whole `/Developer` structure inside the app bundle. Everything that was in `/Developer` is now in `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

The path to lipo would now be `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo`

You can use xcode-select to get the path to lipo of the current Xcode version (useful if you use beta versions, because you can use xcode-select to switch between release and beta version without changing your scripts):

```
LIPO=`xcode-select -p`/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo
```

And if you install the `Xcode Command Line Tools` you will have a `lipo` in your system path (i.e. `/usr/bin/lipo`), so you don't need to create those path variables at all. The command line tools download should be available in the *Downloads* tab of Xcodes Preferences panel.